# Aggregate Remove and De-aggregate

Tags: r, count, aggregate, data-cleaning

I want to sum up several variables for customer numbers and then exclude those with the sum of 0, since X1 can be positive and negative. After excluding them I would like to "Deaggregate" it again, is that somehow possible?

```
AggData <- aggregate(cbind(X1, X2, X3, X4, X4, X5, X6, X7)~ CustomerNumber + 
Date + Accountnumber, mydata, sum)
ClearedData <- AggData[mydata$X1!=0,]
```

Moreover, I would like to create a new variable that counts the Dates and measures the recurrence, can you help me with that?

Comment: If you want to exclude the rows where the sum is equal to zero, I think you need `ClearedData <- AggData[AggData$X1!=0,]`. Then you need to select from `mydata` using the categories from `ClearedData`.

Comment: can you provide code to make (dummy) data which is representative of your data please

Comment: also split this in to two questions - the two parts (aggregate/deaggregate and the counting of dates) are unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first ("aggregate and de-aggregate") question (the two questions are unrelated, it is more appropriate to split them into two separate questions, please do ask unrelated questions in one post).

By the looks of it you have data of 7 columns containing numeric values which can be positive or negative, and columns containing customer numbers etc. Some dummy data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(-5:5), size = 70, replace = T), ncol = 7))
df1$CN <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

You want to sum those across the rows, and exclude the rows where the sum = 0. To do that, use `apply` and `subset`:

```
df1$SUM <- apply(df1[,1:7], 1, sum)
subset(df1, df1$SUM != 0)
```